# Jupyter Notebook: Force cookie expiration and reset token

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How can I remove access to a Jupyter Notebook server to previous users? I did a quick setup of a Jupyter Notebook server and provided access to a few users. Now that it's no longer needed, how can I force the authentication cookies to expire and reset the authentication token?

I think I should have used JupyterHub, but I didn't know about it then.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Stop the server, run `jupyter notebook password` and set/change your password.

Comment: But what if I don't use and don't want to use a password? Tokens and cookies work great for me.

Comment: Then change c.NotebookApp.token = 'your_new_token' into your config

Comment: I don't think this method works as I tested and discovered that a previously logged-in browser can still log in.

Comment: This method doesn't work as a previously logged in user can still use the session even after a password reset

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete the runtime files as well as the change the password.

You can get the path to the runtime files with `jupyter --paths`
Also see https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/use/jupyter-directories.html#runtime-files

Answer (score 0):

Logout (top right menu), and restart the Jupyter Notebook.  You will need the new token to login.

Recommend you require users use an SSH tunnel to access the jupyter notebook.  That is, block the notebook's port at the server's firewall level.

```
# Authenticate to Server
ssh -L local_port:localhost:server_port user1@my.server.com

# For example
ssh -L 8899:localhost:8888 user1@my.server.com
```

Now user1 can open a web browser on their machine and go to http://localhost:8899 to access the notebook running on my.server.com:8888.